# Take a look on a website with specified viewport size, that is bigger than physical size?

Tags: resolution, screenshot

My display driver's maximum screen width is 1280 pixels.

I need to test a website with resolution 1920×1080 pixels. Or 3000×5000.

Different browsers is optional.

Comment: Simalar question "set-window-size-larger-than-screen size"
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947184/how-to-set-browser-window-size-larger-than-is-screen-resolution-in-windows-xp

Comment: Actually the link you have mentioned in the comment will do the job for only browser's window. It will not take effect for the resolution size of the web page. Resolution matters in the different way.

Answer (score 1):

#### Firefox

```
Menu -> Developer -> Responsive Design Mode (Ctrl-Shift-M)
```

gives you a drop-down to select the window size. There is also a button to create a Screenshot at this exact size. If the chosen viewport is larger than the screen, scroll bars will appear.

[image: responsive design of this page set to 1920x1080]